# Insert data in mysql table if sum of a column is greater or equal to specific integer

Tags: mysql

I am trying to Run this Query

```
INSERT INTO point(description, username, _by, date_time, p) 
VALUES ('Test By System','username','System',now(),if( (SELECT SUM(p) FROM point WHERE username = 'username') - 1 >=0 , - 1 ,0));
```

The thing i am really trying to achieve is if SUM of a column is greater or equal to 1 2 or 3 then insert a new Row in the Table.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Welcome to SO Family. Your question is not clear. Add some more details about your question with table structure, sample Data and desired output/objective you want to achieve

Comment: Use `INSERT .. SELECT` with proper WHERE clause instead of `INSERT .. VALUES` (and maybe with proper CASE in SELECT expression).